# Reading grades from text file into an array C++

Tags: c++

So I have a text document that holds the data

StudentID grade1 grade2 grade3

1234        80     90    100

2000        12     24     36

3000        13     85     97

How can I store only the grade1 numbers into an array to use for manipulation such as finding averages?

Here is the code I have so far.

```
string fileName = "grades.txt";
ifstream fin;
fin.open(fileName);
if (!fin)
{
    cout << fileName << " is not found. " << endl;
    system("pause");
    exit(0);
}


int examnum;
int examchoice1;
int n = 0;
int examarray[3];
double exam1;
double exam2;
double exam3;

//double average = 0;

cout << "Which exam would you like to view statistics of?: ";
cin >> examnum;
while (examnum < 1 || examnum > 3)
{
    cout << "Please enter a valid exam to view: ";
    cin >> examnum;
}

if (examnum == 1) 
{
        while (fin >> studentID >> examchoice1 >> exam2
            >> exam3)
        {
            examchoice1 >> examarray[n];
            n++;
        }


}
fin.close();
```

Comment: Must be an assignment due today, second question about this today. Anyway, `examchoice1 >> examarray[n]` is not how you do assignments. `>>` is used to read from `istream` objects. You want `=`, and the other way around.

Comment: Thank you ChrisMM!